# Query does not return results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

There are the following data:

```
create (_66:`User` {`ban`:4, `banned`:1, `chitaet`:942, `chitateli`:444, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:118});
create (_67:`User` {`ban`:0, `banned`:0, `chitaet`:26, `chitateli`:59, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:119});
create _66<-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]-_67;
create _66-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]->_67;
```

Why does the following query return no results?

```
MATCH (a:`User`)-[:FOLLOW {lenta:'main'}]->(b:`User`) WHERE a.`id` = 118 RETURN b.id AS id LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the queries are executed sequentially, thus when Neo4j reaches:

```
create _66<-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]-_67;
```

it does not know what `_66` or `_67` are.
Try:

```
create (_66:`User` {`ban`:4, `banned`:1, `chitaet`:942, `chitateli`:444, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:118})
,(_67:`User` {`ban`:0, `banned`:0, `chitaet`:26, `chitateli`:59, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:119})
, _66<-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]-_67
, _66-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]->_67;
```

Something similar always works for my database.

I suggest you return some values also. This way you can verify that the create statement executed successfully

```
create (_66:`User` {`ban`:4, `banned`:1, `chitaet`:942, `chitateli`:444, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:118}),
(_67:`User` {`ban`:0, `banned`:0, `chitaet`:26, `chitateli`:59, `disable_r`:0, `disabled_r`:0, `hide`:0, `id`:119}), 
_66<-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]-_67,
_66-[:`FOLLOW` {`id`:54820, `lenta`:"main", `time`:1436720633}]->_67,
return _66,_67;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your `User` label- you're querying for `Users` instead.
Try

```
MATCH (a:`User`)-[:FOLLOW {lenta:'main'}]->(b:`User`) WHERE a.`id` = 118 RETURN b.id AS id LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Here's the graph you posted- http://console.neo4j.org/r/d171mv and the query works. Have you posted the right data/query?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It turned out I was not properly inserted data.